# Why when I add nginx to docker do I get the error: /bin/sh: pip: not found

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, pip, docker-compose

If I add

```
FROM nginx:1.16-alpine
```

to my Dockerfile, my build breaks with the error:

```
/bin/sh: pip: not found
```

I tried sending an update command via :

```
RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install python-pip
```

but then I get the error that apt-get can't be found.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.2-alpine
FROM nginx:1.16-alpine

ENV INSTALL_PATH /web

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:9000 --access-logfile - "web.webhook_server:create_app()"
```

If I remove that one line:

```
FROM nginx:1.16-alpine
```

it all runs fine.  But of course, I need nginx.

What could be going wrong here?  I'm very confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: Combine multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214757/docker-combine-multiple-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14412#issuecomment-118995461):

> Using multiple FROM is not really a feature but a bug [...]
>
> Note that :
>   - There is discussion to remove support for multiple FROM : #13026

So you should decide for one image that fits you most and then intall the necessary packages you need via [RUN apk add](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md#example). Note that both images you used as base are based themself on *alpine linux* and you need to use `apk` instead of `apt-get` to install packages.

Comment: Thanks for this.  That does make sense (I'm quite new at docker / compose in general).  I just swapped them over to test, I commented out the `FROM python:3.7.2-alpine` and left the `FROM nginx:1.16-alpine` and I get the same error.  If I do it the other way around though it works.  So it seems the list `FROM nginx:1.16-alpine` is the issue?

Comment: You mean you get the same error that `apt-get` was not found? Thats due to the reason that you need to use `apk` instead. So exchange the `RUN apt-get ...` block with: `RUN apk add --update py-pip`

Comment: OK my bad, I didn't follow your full comment (or know what it meant fully).  Some research later and I've added `run apk update` and `run apk add py-pip` to the Dockerfile and it's working.  Thank you for your help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use "FROM nginx:1.16" instead of "FROM nginx:1.16-alpine". The alpine image doesn't have apt. With "nginx:1.16" you can install your extra packages with apt.

The FROM directive tells the docker daemon to extend from an image. You cannot extend from 2 different images.

Let me know if this helps.