# How can I run TWO Docker images in a SINGLE Container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I want to create a Single Docker Container with **PHP Image** & **Apache Image**, here is my dockerfile.

**Docker File Name:** single-container.dockerfile

```
# PHP image from docker hub
FROM php:7.2-cli


# Apache image from docker hub
FROM httpd:2.4

# public-html is path for my local codebase
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

In docker CLI when I run this command: `docker build -f single-container.dockerfile . -t mysinglecontainer:latest`

> I'm getting below error.

[image]

Please advice, what are the changes needs to modify?

Comment: As you know this is how running containers looks like:

Dockerfile > Build Image > Run Container.

Outcome of single docker file will be one container,but you can use multi-step build to make it optimized. Here:
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: Combine multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214757/docker-combine-multiple-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution**

> Here is my Github URL: [https://github.com/yogig/dockercron/](https://github.com/yogig/dockercron/blob/master/docker-compose.php.dockerfile)

```html
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

LABEL maintainer="xxx@xxx.de" \
      muz.customer="xxx" \
      muz.product="xxx" \
      container.mode="development"

#https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .deps autoconf tzdata build-base libzip-dev mysql-dev gmp-dev \
            libxml2-dev libpng-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev jpeg-dev icu-dev openldap-dev libxslt-dev &&\
    docker-php-ext-install zip xml mbstring json intl gd pdo pdo_mysql iconv soap \
                           dom gmp fileinfo sockets bcmath mysqli ldap xsl &&\
    echo 'date.timezone="Europe/Berlin"' >> "${PHP_INI_DIR}"/php.ini &&\
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime &&\
    echo 'Europe/Berlin' > /etc/timezone &&\
    curl -s https://www.phing.info/get/phing-latest.phar > /bin/phing &&\
    chmod a+x /bin/phing &&\
    ln -s /bin/phing /usr/local/bin/phing &&\
    ln -s /bin/phing /usr/local/phing &&\
    ln -s /bin/phing /usr/bin/phing &&\
    apk del .deps &&\
    apk add --no-cache libzip mysql libxml2 libpng zlib freetype jpeg icu gmp git subversion libxslt openldap \
            apache2 apache2-ldap apache2-proxy libreoffice openjdk11-jre ghostscript msttcorefonts-installer \
            terminus-font ghostscript-fonts &&\
    ln -s /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2/modules &&\
    ln -s /usr/sbin/httpd /etc/init.d/httpd &&\
    update-ms-fonts

# copy crontabs for root user
COPY crontab.txt /etc/crontabs/root

#https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/3ebff8dadf1e38dbe694ea0b8f379f6b8bcd993e/2.4/alpine/httpd-foreground
#https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/alpine3.10/fpm/Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "rm -f /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid && httpd -DBACKGROUND && php-fpm"]
```

> will install PHP Alpine image

```
(1) FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine
```

> Configuration for Apache

```
(2) apk add --no-cache libzip mysql libxml2 libpng zlib freetype jpeg icu gmp git subversion libxslt openldap \
            apache2 apache2-ldap apache2-proxy libreoffice openjdk11-jre ghostscript msttcorefonts-installer \
            terminus-font ghostscript-fonts
```

**Last**: In Docker CLI, I run the command `docker-compose up` and now in my Single Container, both PHP & Apache is running successfully.

> Note: To see content of docker-compose.yaml file, visit
>   https://github.com/yogig/dockercron

Answer (score 5):

move the `.` to the end

```
docker build -f httpd.Dockerfile -t mysinglecontainer:latest .
```

be sure to use the correct `Dockerfile` name also in your command the name is `single-container.dockerfile`

so the command is:

```
docker build -f single-container.dockerfile -t mysinglecontainer:latest .
```

Comment: Yes, made the changes

Comment: I run this command: docker build -f  single-container.dockerfile -t mysinglecontainer:latest .

it works fine but at the end I got this error:




`Step 3/3 : COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder162671660/public-html: no such file or directory`

Comment: I am starting to think that you are missundertanding what multistage build do ..........

Comment: This doesn't answer my questions. I need 1 container which has PHP & Apache both. and one single image with PHP &  Apache when I run `docker images` I need only one image, after running above code, I have got 2 separate images for PHP & Apache.

Comment: please understand first what multistage do, https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ . i was trying to help you get the concept . to run the both you need to install one of the service manually using dockerfile.......

Comment: understand the document, and I found the solution, in single dockerfile, I called PHP & Apache & it worked.