# How can I write a Dockerfile to merge two or more docker images into one?

Tags: windows, docker, openvino, streamlit

I am trying to integrate three things into one docker image.

The first image is: https://github.com/opencv/gst-video-analytics

The second image is: https://github.com/domoritz/streamlit-docker

The third image is: http://blog.feabhas.com/2020/02/running-the-eclipse-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-in-a-docker-container/

Can someone guide me on how can I integrate these three images into one on docker in Windows 10?

```
Operating system: Windows 10 

Docker version 19.03.1
```

Comment: See _e.g._ [Docker: Combine multiple images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214757/docker-combine-multiple-images) or [Is there a way to combine Docker images into 1 container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626579/is-there-a-way-to-combine-docker-images-into-1-container).  There's no way to programatically merge multiple images into one.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar with [docker-combos](https://github.com/kichik/docker-combo). You basically just include all the lines from all three `Dockerfile` files, but only one `FROM` line. Then start correcting errors as they come up. You may have a bunch of errors because the `FROM` lines aren't the same (one is Ubuntu, one is Alpine so you have to change `apk add` to `apt-get install`).

You can also consider not using a single Docker container for all these and go with `docker-compose`. It lets you bring up multiple containers all together and link their network for easy access.